# Missing tiles in OSM

Tags: leaflet, maps

I am creating a basic map app. When I load the tiles, the map is shown in blocks and not the full map.

Image is here what it looks like.

[image: screenshot]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABgGw.jpg

What is wrong?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7/leaflet.css" />
    <script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v1.6.4/mapbox.js'></script>
    <style type="text/css">
    #map {
        width: 600px;
        height: 400px;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var mapboxTiles = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: '<a href="http://www.mapbox.com/about/maps/" target="_blank">Terms &amp; Feedback</a>'
    });

    var map = L.map('map')
        .addLayer(mapboxTiles)
        .setView([35.65188895052401,-97.43681781720626], 10);
        var marker = L.marker([35.65188895052401,-97.43681781720626]).addTo(map);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You will get a better response by replacing osm.org with openstreetmap.org - also the attribution should be Openstreetmap https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright not Mapbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typical CSS issue, probably due to mix usage of Leaflet and mapbox.js

If you want to use mapbox.js, you probably need a specific CSS file from mapbox as well. And you probably do not need Leaflet JS and CSS files.

Comment: The code is leaflet, so mapbox.js is not needed.  But that is not the problem, it is the performance of osm.org vs openstreetmap.org (which can also be seen using OpenLayers).